# How can I create image of published google sheet to send in sms?

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I'm new to this and I was wondering how I can send a chart from google sheets via sms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does SMS support to send chart? Can you send it manually?

Comment: add more details